# Assigning to a var inside an if statement in php

Tags: php, mysql

The code below is supposed to check whether the name already exists in the database, and if it is already there then set a boolean. But it does set the boolean even if the name does not exist; I've verified this many times. So I think it must be my code that's wrong. I understand the line below as a check to see

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

I think this line is checking whether there was result found at all. If a result is found then the conditional evaluates to TRUE, so `$row` gets assigned. Is that correct?

Do you see any other problems with the code or something that is done badly? I'm suspicious of the line that contains the `mysql_query` since sometimes, when you search for a name that's not in the table of the database, it still enters the `if` block.

```
$udid_mismatch = false;
$name_found = false;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT udid 
                         FROM $table 
                        WHERE name='$name'");

if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $name_found = true;

  if($row['udid'] != $udid) {
    $udid_mismatch = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: It should work. Try `mysql_num_rows` to be sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$udid_mismatch = $name_found = false;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `udid `
                         FROM `$table `
                        WHERE `name` = '$name'");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $name_found = true;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row['udid'] != $udid) {
            $udid_mismatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I started to write that you should use equality instead of equal, then realized I was jumping to conclusions.

mysql_fetch_assoc returns an array if data exists, or FALSE if no rows are left.  My hunch is $row is never getting set to FALSE.  I would try debugging $row and checking what values are returned when no name is found.  If it's assigning an empty array, that's still going to evaluate to true.

Your logic is sound in using equality inside your if statement.  If it equates to FALSE, your if statement won't run.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

Will enter the if statement if the assignment evaluates to true (ie is not equal false/0/null)

You are not looping over the rows for a start, change the IF to a WHILE

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

to

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

Comment: also, you've not specified $udid in the snippet